# Crystal report viewer not wraping correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm using Crystal reports 13 on visual studio 2010.

I have a report that is displayed in a CrystalViewerReport control and almost everything is ok except that with some details the text is not wraping correctly and some of the content is displayed out of the field area.

This only occurs in the viewer because if I export it as PDF the text is ok and no information is overlapped. So I would like to know if there is some configuration that I should apply on the control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Wrap your Text, Right Click on the textobject ,choose the `formate object`,Check the `can grow Textbox`,THus you can wrap your text.